# how to configure postgres in docker to connect to it remotely

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-connection, psql

I use Postgres which is run in Docker in one virtual machine and I would like to connect to this Postgres on the other virtual machine using:

```
psql -h \<IP_Address\> -p \<port_no\> -d \<database_name\> -U \<DB_username\>.
```

I know I have to change pga_hba.file, but I also know that the contents of the container cannot be changed. I think the best way would be to add a volume with pga_hba.conf, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I will be very grateful for your help.

I tried this command:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=db_tes -v /var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgis/postgis:13-master
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `pg_hba` file in postgresql container is configured for expose port `5432` on `0.0.0.0`. and you don't need to create volume for this.

assume your machine ip is `192.168.1.2`. run your container in this way:

```sh
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=db_tes -v /var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:13.6
```

check your firewall (may be port `5432` is blocked). now postgres is listening on: `192.168.1.2:5432`

and you can connect to this with this command on your other machine (if they are in same subnet). assume your other machine ip is `192.168.1.25`:

```sh
psql -h 192.168.1.2 -p 5432 -d <database_name> -U <DB_username> -p
```

and then you can see your db.

(sorry for my awful english)